# How to return multiple dataframes using @pandas_udf in Pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, scikit-learn, user-defined-functions

I want to create sklearn's `train_test_split` function for Pyspark. I am using pandas udf for creating this function

This is what I have done.

```
@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def load_dataset(dataset):
    
    feature_columns = cols
    label = 'y';
    X = dataset[feature_columns]
    Y = dataset[label]
 
    # splitting the dataset into train and test
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)
    print(X_train)
 
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
```

I want these dataframes X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test seperately.

I know that udf function is called like this

```
df.groupby("key").apply(load_dataset).show()
```

But I dont know what to use in place of
`key`
Also, this returns single dataframe and I want four.

Comment: I am 100% certain pyspark has this function already.

Comment: If you just want to split your dataframes you can use [randomSplit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.randomSplit)

Comment: But I dont want to use randomsplit, actually I want to use sklearn 's train_test_split function into Pyspark.

Comment: Can you suggest me that link? @John Stud

Comment: As far as I know, this is just not possible with pandas_udf. You can't return 4 Spark DataFrames. Please read the docs [Pandas Function APIs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#pandas-function-apis).

Comment: @John Stud. Can you share the details of how this can be done. I am also looking for the same functionality but have not been able to find it.

Comment: What is wrong with: `df = inputDF.cache()`, `a,b = df.randomSplit([0.5, 0.5])`. For time series where order matters, use `df = df.withColumn("rank", percent_rank().over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy("departure_time")))` , `train_df = df.where("rank <= .8").drop("rank", "departure_time")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I had to do the Subsampling. That is why i had to get the four variables returns from train_test_split function. But I concatenated X_test and y_test and returned a single dataframe.

```
@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def load_dataset(dataset):
    
    feature_columns = cols
    label = 'y';
    X = dataset[feature_columns]
    Y = dataset[label]
 
    # splitting the dataset into train and test
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)
    print(X_train)
    
    df_sample = pd.concat([X_test, y_test], axis=1)
 
    return df_sample
```

And this code is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with:

```
df = inputDF.cache()
a,b = df.randomSplit([0.5, 0.5])
```

For time series where order matters, use:

```
df = df.withColumn("rank", percent_rank().over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy("departure_time")))

train_df = df.where("rank <= .8").drop("rank", "departure_time")
```

Comment: I want to do the subsampling on X_test and y_test dataframes by using sklearn's train_test_split.

Comment: Can you offer more insight? Why not generate X_test and y_test like I specified above, and then do the same process again to "subsample"?

Comment: I think randomsplit is not great for subsampling that is why I want to create a pandas udf for train_test_split of sklearn so that I can use it.